# Multiple Command Bars in Windows Phone 8.1 in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 I can define my Bottom Command Bar like so:

```
<Page {...}>
    <Grid>
        {...}
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Label="Refresh" Icon="Refresh" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Help" Icon="Help" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>

            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Label="Edit" Icon="Edit" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
                <AppBarButton Label="Remove" Icon="Remove" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
                <AppBarButton Label="Add" Icon="Add" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

This is fine for just one Bar, however, how can I change it to another if the user clicks in the Help button? Just in XAML.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23180401/2681948) how I do it.

Comment: Ok, but how do I do that in XAML only?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with XAML only.

Comment: You can try making a XAML markup for both app bars and then show / hide buttons depending on a context: [How to add contextual commands to an app bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150603.aspx). You can also try creating a [CommandBar styles and/or templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481537.aspx) in XAML resource dictionary and then switching them in the code behind (though I can't say for sure that this works).