# Multiple CommandBars in single Page winrt WP 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I have currently one BottomPage CommandBar and i was wandering if it is possible to change that command bar via similar mechanic to the one described here : [This is tut for WP 7 and 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394036%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) ?

Comment: AFAIK - No. You will have to do it [via code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23180401/2681948).

Comment: I was afraid that's the case. Thanks for such quick reply