# How to add Multiple AppBar/CommandBar's in xaml page itself in windows phone 8.1 runtime app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

i have implemented mvvm in my application(Prism) so every logic will comes in viewmodel so i dont want to create the appbar/commandbar from code behind, in xaml page it is not supporting more than one appbar/commandbar, i have gone through many blogs but i couldn't find any solution for my need, but i got the suggestion like by using dependency property in base page it can be done, but i have no idea how to implement it, so could any one help me regarding this. Thanks in advance :)

My code is below what i have done in code behind.(first app bar in xaml and second in code behind)

Xaml:

```
<storeApps:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="firstBar">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

                 <AppBarButton Label="Proceed">

                    <AppBarButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/next.png"/>
                    </AppBarButton.Icon>

                </AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
</storeApps:VisualStateAwarePage.BottomAppBar>
```

CS Code:

```
 CommandBar secondBar;


        public HomePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            PrepareAppBars();

        }
        private void PrepareAppBars()
        {
            secondBar= new CommandBar();
            secondBar.IsOpen = true;

            AppBarButton btnHome = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/home.png") } };
            btnHome.Label = "Home";

            btnHome.IsEnabled = true;

            AppBarButton btnWallet = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/wallet.png") } };
            btnWallet.Label = "Wallet";

            btnWallet.IsEnabled = true;

            AppBarButton btnAccount = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/account.png") } };
            btnAccount.Label = "Account";

            btnAccount.IsEnabled = true;

            AppBarButton btnUpdate = new AppBarButton() { Icon = new BitmapIcon() { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/update.png") } };
            btnUpdate.Label = "Update";

            btnUpdate.IsEnabled = true;

            secondBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(btnHome);
            secondBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(btnWallet);
            secondBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(btnAccount);
            secondBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(btnUpdate);    


            BottomAppBar = secondBar;
        }


 private void HomePivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (HomePivot.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    BottomAppBar = secondBar;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    BottomAppBar = firstBar;
                    break;
                default:
                    BottomAppBar = null;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same requirement, I am going to try this solution: you can use XAML to define the buttons and ViewModel (MVVM pattern) to control the visibility of these buttons. Make the buttons in different groups. Define a property in your view model, and this property is used to show the different groups of buttons, so you need to bind that property in your XAML.
Check this [Multiple AppBar/CommandBars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23179112/multiple-appbar-commandbars)

Answer (score -1):

You can add something like this to use Bottom Appbar, you can have up to 4 button with icon

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="btmAppbar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh"
                      Label="Refresh"
                      x:Name="RefreshButton"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Help"
                      x:Name="HelpButton"
                      Label="Help"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

To add more button you have to use secondary command

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="btmAppbar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh"
                      Label="Refresh"
                      x:Name="RefreshButton"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Help"
                      x:Name="HelpButton"
                      Label="Help"/>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="FirstSecondary"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: This is not what i actually asked, if you have gone through the question once you will come to know, i want multiple appbars which needs to be created in xaml page because i want to handle all my button commands and events in viewmodel. I want multiple appbars because i want to use those in pivot item index changed.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show different AppBar for different pivot item?

Comment: yeah, i can add or remove the buttons from code behind page or i can add multiple app bar from code behind but that is not what i want because i want to handle every thing in view model itself.